# Where is HTML5 Boilerplate on projects created by Yeoman Webapp Generator?

Tags: javascript, yeoman, boilerplate

I am starting to learn and code with [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) to speed my application development. For my first application i used the [Webapp Generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp), that they say it's a generator that comes already with Yeoman (for me didn't come, i had to install it with NPM).

Anyway, when you start this webapp generator with Yeoman, it says in the beginning that includes HTML5 Boilerplate, jQuery and Modernizr.

Looking at the project folder, i couldn't find any sign of Boilerplate, i never used it before, but i thought it had at least to have a main.css and a normalize.css file included in the project. The only thing it has is a main.css with this styles:

```
body {
    background: #fafafa;
}

canvas {
    border: 1px dotted black;
}

.hero-unit {
    margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
}
```

I think it has boilerplate included, but i really need your help to find, so where is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be working as designed:

https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/issues/427

"We made a decision not to include normalize as we currently opt for Twitter Bootstrap, which includes its own resets as our default. If we change our mind about this in the future however its certainly possible we might reconsider including normalize."

Comment: I think this issue is about the 'quickstart' generator, but it seems that the reason they gave apply to the 'webapp' generator. Thanks!